# How to make js file load asynchronously in joomla template file

Tags: php, asynchronous, joomla, cache-control, pagespeed

I am using joomla. In it's template js are being called like following way-

```
 $doc->addScript($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/javascript/cscript.js', 'text/javascript');
```

I just want to add tag `async` to it. How should i do that..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass 4th param with boolean `true`,

```
$doc->addScript($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/javascript/cscript.js', 'text/javascript', false, true);
```

Comment: what is this `false` indicate..??

Comment: Hey @Rakesh can i do the same thing via inserting a code in the javascript.?

Comment: I asked that because i found this code - `a.async=1;` on one of my javascript that is written in the index file.